# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un div quede fixed a la derecha mientras muevo contenido?

Tags: jquery, css3, bootstrap-4, div, material-design

Actualmente estoy realizando un sitio con fullpage js y material design orientado a bootstrap 4 y quiero que uno de los section tenga un div estático que replete el lado derecho y el contenido quede normal que se pueden agregar elementos como siempre, lo importante es el lado derecho. El código que llevo es el siguiente

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2'],
  scrollOverflow: true,
  autoScrolling: true,
  paddingTop: '30px',
  loopBottom: true,
  css3: true,
  menu: "#menu",

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" id="section1">
    <section id="quienes-somos" class="col-md-12 h-100 d-flex">
      <div class="row  justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
          <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Marketing/mdb-press-pack/mdb-main.jpg" class="img-fluid z-depth-1-half" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
          <!-- Main heading -->
          <h3 class="h3 mb-3">
            Contenido Titulo
          </h3>
          <p>
            Descripcion para mostrar algun contenido aquí
          </p>
          <!-- Main heading -->
          <hr>
          <p>
            Segundo parrafo de descripción para el contenido
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" id="section2">
    <section id="servicios" class=" row col-md-12">
      <div class="row col-md-10">
        <div class="card mb-3 ml-4 col-md-3">
          <!--Card image-->
          <div class="view overlay">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/16.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <a href="#!">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-blue btn-md">Read more</button>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card mb-3 ml-4 col-md-3">
          <!--Card image-->
          <div class="view overlay">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/16.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <a href="#!">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-blue btn-md">Read more</button>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card mb-3 ml-4 col-md-3">
          <!--Card image-->
          <div class="view overlay">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/16.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <a href="#!">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-blue btn-md">Read more</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-4 bg-dark">
        <ul>
          <li>1111</li>
          <li>2222</li>
          <li>3333</li>
          <li>4444</li>
          <li>5555</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero que el que esta de color negro quede full altura fixed y que solo los card se puedan mover(*No se si llego a explicar bien*), pero esa es la idea.

> PD:hagna en ejecutable del snnipet en pantalla completa para que se
>   pueda apreciar mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar usar ScrollMagic (o alguna librería que te facilite funciones con scroll) y utilizar el método .setPin().

[Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html)

También es posible con CSS al usar la propiedad `position:sticky`

[Aqui puedes encontrar ejemplos y guía de uso](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta , probare algunas cosas.

Comment: nop, no funciona me tira abajo en scrollmagic, el div me lo deja abajo.

Comment: Justo estoy haciendo un sitio con esta característica, [es este](http://mireina.mx/qa). ¿Tienes alguna visualización de cómo te aparece en tu implementación?

Comment: esque no tengo subido el sitio y con imagenes no senota mucho porque es igual como aparece en el snnipet en pantalla completa.PD: esta bueno tu sitio .

Comment: lo que pasa es que si agrego mas cards al section del fullpage se genera una barra lateral y lo que quiero es que se mantega a medida que baja en el section.

Comment: ¿No te funcionaría tener esa barra lateral con `position : absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` y utilizar el evento de fullPage `onSlideLeave`? Verificas el id de la sección y cambias `position : absolute;` por `position : fixed;`

Comment: interesante aaa, lo veré no habia visto esta parte de la documentación.}+

Comment: ya lo probe como dijiste y parece que no funcionará por que no toma como scroll en que genera el fullpage

Comment: Lo que veo es que estás utilizando una extensión, que es la de `scrollOverflow`, ¿no hay algún método que te permita escuchar el "scroll" de la sección que tiene scroll overflow?

Comment: no o he visto en a documentación , no se que mas puede ser

Comment: ¿Probaste con `position:sticky` de CSS?

Comment: asi es @Balo, ya lo he probao ya